# How do I install the marble plasmoid in KDE 5.9.0?

Tags: kubuntu, 15.04, kde, plasma

I recently upgraded from Kubuntu Utopic Unicorn (14.10) to Vivid Vervet (15.04).  In the process, I lost the marble plasmoid that showed a day/night world map on my background.  I have the `marble` package installed, which includes files such as `/usr/bin/marble`, `/usr/share/kde4/services/plasma-applet-kworldclock.desktop`, `/usr/share/applications/kde4/marble.desktop`, and others.  However, it does not include a `.plasmoid` file that I apparently need for [installing new plasmoids](https://userbase.kde.org/Plasma/Installing_Plasmoids).  How do I get back to the situation where I had the world day/night view on my desktop?

Comment: Did you solve the problem?:>

Comment: @404pio No, I didn't.  I've not had a day/night world map as desktop background since the upgrade.